# How to convert excel file to pdf file using vb6 program?

Tags: vb6

Can anyone give me an idea on how to convert excel file to pdf file using vb6?

Answer (score 0):

You'll most likely just want a pdf tool that can be used from VB. See this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255048/how-can-i-programatically-print-a-datareport-to-a-pdf-file/6255508#6255508).