# How can i perform Print on a pdf which i have cretaed

Tags: objective-c, pdf, ios5, printing

I have created a method for generating the pdf and use this as mail attachment.But i want to use the same pdf for the print purpose.How can i do this?thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if [Adobe Reader Command Line Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619158/adobe-reader-command-line-reference) fits your needs.
If you don't have Acrobat Reader (maybe in server environment) you can try [How to print PDF on default network printer using GhostScript (gswin32c.exe) shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599925/how-to-print-pdf-on-default-network-printer-using-ghostscript-gswin32c-exe-she)