# Programatically print PDF file using Windows Spooler API

Tags: c, windows, printing, print-spooler-api

Is it possible to print a PDF file from using windows Spooler API. I tried with below code and it is not working...

```
int print_handle = 0;   
OpenPrinter(pPrinterName, &print_handle, NULL);
if (print_handle == 0)
{
    return 0;
}
docinfo1.pDocName = (LPTSTR)("My PDF");
docinfo1.pOutputFile = NULL;
docinfo1.pDatatype = (LPTSTR)("RAW");
temp = StartDocPrinter(print_handle, 1, &docinfo1);
temp = StartPagePrinter(print_handle);
temp = WritePrinter(print_handle, (LPBYTE)filebuff, filelen, &bytes_written);
EndPagePrinter(print_handle);
EndDocPrinter(print_handle);
```

WritePrinter function return SUCCESS and nothing got printed. Printing TXT and PRN file using this API is working.

Comment: That's not going to work for the reasons Nick Westgate explained in his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows has no built-in ability to print PDF files.

You'll have to use an external application or library, e.g. [Ghostscript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2599925/313445).

I should note that because your code uses the "RAW" datatype (like the [official sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162959(v=vs.85).aspx)) it is sending the written job data directly to the printer. ASCII data works because practically all printers can receive and print ASCII. If the printer understood PDF as a PDL (Page Description Language - other examples are PCL or PostScript), it would print your PDF. But for all other printers the PDF needs to be converted into a PDL the printer understands.

Comment: Defining PDL on first use would improve your answer.

Comment: At least can i print a DOC file or a IMG file using this API?  Or for this also i need to convert it using some external library...

Comment: The Windows print APIs you're using are very low-level and know nothing about application-level files like PDF and DOC. Please read this [overview of Windows printing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/introduction-to-printing). Only MS Word (and a few other applications and libraries) know how to print DOC files. Images can be printed, but need higher level APIs. Even then you'll probably need a library for anything other than BMP. Google for "windows print image C++" or use .NET if you can, because that will be easier.

Comment: You can use Ghostscript to convert PDF to images. Then you can print those images